# Сохранять boolean значение в state после перезагрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Подскажите пожалуйста, как после перезагрузки страницы сохранять boolean значение в state?

```
constructor(props: ICommentsSectionProps, state: ICommentsSectionState) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      reverse: false;
   };
}
```

Значение reverse меняется по клику на кнопку.

```
<DefaultButton onClick={() => this.setState({ reverse: !reverse })} />
```

На изменение reverse вешаются значения flex-direction.

```
<div style={{flexDirection: reverse ? 'column-reverse' : 'column' }} >...</div>
```

По клику, значение меняется на true, элементы меняют направление.
Однако, после перезагрузки страницы, значение опять возвращается на false.

Comment: Чтоб состояние сохранялось после перезагрузки страницы - его нужно где-то предварительно сохранить)

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое, положить информацию в **localStorage**

По клику, записываем значение, которое будет иметь условный вид false true но в виде строк :)

```
<DefaultButton onClick={() => {
  localStorage.setItem('reverse', reverse ? '' : '1');
  this.setState({ reverse: !reverse });
}} 
/>
```

При создании компонента, считываем информацию из хранилища и если пустая строка, то будет **false**, если строка не пустая, будет **true**. Для конвертации используем двойное отрицание **!!**

```
constructor(props: ICommentsSectionProps, state: ICommentsSectionState) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      reverse: !!localStorage.getItem('reverse');
   };
}
```

Comment: Какой-то redux получился 

Comment: @ЕвгенийКолмак Почему это redux?